# GroovyClassLoader - Isolate from parent class loader

Tags: java, groovy, classloader

I'm trying to run Groovy scripts inside my Java Application using the `GroovyClassLoader` and the `GroovyScriptEngineImpl`, and I want to isolate the Groovy script from the parent application context.

What I mean is that when I'm running my Groovy script, I don't want it to inherit from the dependencies loaded in my Java application in order to be able to, for example, load `Gson 2.5.5` in my script, even if my Java application is using `Gson 3.4.1`.

```
// Replacing the context class loader with the system one
ClassLoader initialCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());

// Creating my GroovyClassLoader and GroovyScriptEngine
GroovyClassLoader groovyCL = new GroovyClassLoader();
GroovyScriptEngineImpl scriptEngine = new GroovyScriptEngineImpl(groovyCL);

// Compiling and running my Groovy script
CompiledScript compiledScript = scriptEngine.compile("println \"hello\"");
compiledScript.eval();

// Going back to my initial classloader
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(initialCL);
```

This way, the isolation is indeed working, but the content of the script is not executed at all (even printing a line in the console for example), and I'm getting no error anywhere.

If I don't update my context classloader before creating the new `GroovyClassLoader`, the script is working fine, but it's inheriting from the parent dependencies.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks :)

**UPDATE** : After a bit more testing, It seems like the compilation is working properly, but the evaluation of the compiled script isn't doing anything. Indeed, I'm getting an error when trying to compile a script that doesn't have all the dependencies needed even tho they're present in my Java application classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, finally figured it out, and this is an interesting one.

I said that there was no error, and while it wasn't printed, I actually had one (quite obvious since it wasn't working...). I managed to get the error by changing slightly my method to execute Groovy scripts using a `GroovyShell` instead of my `GroovyScriptEngineImpl` and `GroovyClassLoader`:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());
GroovyClassLoader groovyCL = new GroovyClassLoader();

new GroovyShell(groovyCL).evaluate("println(\"test\")");
```

And here's the error I'm finally getting and that was, for some reason, hidden during my previous executions, not using the `GroovyShell`:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to create Script instance for class: class Script1. Reason: java.lang.ClassCastException: Script1 cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyObject
```

---

### So what's the problem?

Well actually, the classloader that will be used to compile the script and the one used to evaluate the compiled script are not the same: `groovyCL` is used to compile the script, and the "current thread" classloader is used to create the `GroovyShell` object and evaluate the script.

This means that the `groovy.lang.GroovyObject` from both classloaders are not compatible, since the class is defined in both classloaders (even tho they're the exact same class codewise).

Then, when trying to cast the `Script1` object created by `groovyCL`, the `GroovyShell` (or the mechanism I used before with `GroovyScriptEngineImpl` etc...) will encounter `ClassCastException`.

This whole thing can lead to funny errors such as:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: groovy.lang.GroovyShell cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyShell
```

---

### The solution

So, what you want to do is to create your `GroovyClassLoader` instance, and, using this classloader, create all the objects of the workflow using reflection:

```
GroovyClassLoader groovyCL = new GroovyClassLoader();

Class groovyShellClazz = groovyCL.loadClass(GroovyShell.class.getName());
Object groovyShellObj = groovyShellClazz.newInstance();
Method evaluateMethod = groovyShellClazz.getMethod("evaluate", String.class);
evaluateMethod.invoke(groovyShellObj, "println(\"test\")");
```

This requires a bit more work, but the script will be compiled and evaluated by the same classloader and the problem will be fixed.

I still have to work on adapting this solution to my initial situation using the `GroovyScriptEngineImpl` but it's the exact same method :)